# is it possible to Generate QR codes with custom dot shapes using Python

Tags: python, qr-code

Is there any way to generate dot shaped QR code generator make using python?
as like the image

[image]

Comment: Should be, since you can create a default QR code. All you need is the total size of that (in pixel) and the module count. From that you know the exact location of center of each square in pixel coordinates. Now read the pixel at that location, and draw your custom shape at that location.